# How to rename/extract files with long names in zip archive

Tags: zip, filename, unzip

I have a zip which contains files with very long names.

If I try to extract on the command line, I get the error "File name too long".
If I use the graphical archive manager it will not extract the files and it will not let me rename them. The same problem occurs if I mount the archive.

I can extract and rename files individually using:

```
unzip -p -c example.zip "long file name.ogg" > shortname.ogg
```

This is impractical with lots of files.

Is there a tool which will truncate filenames as they are extracted?

Comment: What's the output of `unzip -l <ARCHIVE>` and how do you want the names truncated? Do you want to retain the directory structure inside the archive during extraction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### To extract

We can use `zipinfo` as a part of this process, it's a program from `zip` package.

```
zipinfo -2 example.zip
```

will only shows the files names in `example.zip`, something look like:

```
file1-long-name-...-bla-bla.html
file2-long-name-...-bla-bla.html
```

so we can use this feature to extract all files:

```
zipinfo -2 example.zip | while read i;
do
  long_fname=${i%.*}
  unzip -p -c example.zip "$i" > "${long_fname:0:250}.${i##*.}"
done;
```

- `long_fname=${i%.*}`: Removes extension from long file name, so in case of file name being less that of 256 character; We're not going to get a duplicate extension.
- `${long_fname:0:250}.${i##*.}`: Creates a new file name with legitimate number of character also adds a `.` and file real extension.

Simply we are looping into files list and extract each of them with a new legitimate file name which is 256 character.

---

#### To rename

You can use `zipnote` command, it's a part of `zip` package too.

*Get a backup of your zip file first.*

Run this command:

```
zipnote example.zip > names
```

Open names using an editor, it's look like this:

```
@ file name long in zip and a lot of other strings in the file name
@ (comment above this line)
@ (zip file comment below this line)
```

Add new file names like this:

```
@ file name long in zip and a lot of other strings in the file name
@=new short name for above file
@ (comment above this line)
@ (zip file comment below this line)
```

Then to rename files use:

```
zipnote -w example.zip < names
```

You renamed them all, you can also write a simple script which do this automatically for you.

Comment: Those are incredibly useful, thanks! I couldn't get the zipnote example to work - and the first one removes the file extension - but that's good enough for what I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer, now it will keep the extension too ;)

Comment: You should use `IFS= read -r i` in case the file names start with white space or contain things that the shell may interpret as escape sequences.

Comment: I was still getting errors at a length of 250. I just lowered it to 100 and everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer didn't work for me for some reason, even after decreasing the output file name to length 100, so instead I just extracted all files at once with `unzip -p > all.txt` and then split the file `all.txt` with `csplit` based on some pattern.

Note that unzip will add lines like

```
------=_Part_4952_1005066427.1638023175221
```

and

```
    boundary="----=_Part_4953_1221949914.1638023175221"
```

which should be removed from the output and probably used to split the file, but I didn't need to do that so how to do this properly is left as an exercise :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version that handles long directory names as well. You can add it as a function to your ~/.bashrc or wherever you store your functions or aliases.

```
unziplong() {
    max_base_len=100
    max_ext_len=15
    zipinfo -1 "$1" | grep -v "/$" | while read orig_path
    do
        new_path=""
        current_path="$orig_path"
        while [[ "$current_path" != "." ]]
        do
            segment="$(basename -- "$current_path")"
            ext="$([[ "$segment" =~ .*\..{1,$max_ext_len}$ ]] && echo ".${segment##*.}" || echo)"
            base="${segment%$ext}"
            segment="/$(xargs <<< "${base:0:$max_base_len}")$(xargs <<< "$ext")"
            new_path="$segment$new_path"
            current_path="$(dirname -- "$current_path")"
        done
        new_path="${new_path:1}"
        new_dir="$(dirname -- "$new_path")"
        mkdir -p "$new_dir"
        unzip -p "$1" "$orig_path" > "$new_path"
    done
}
```

Comment: Very readable code. Nice work!